# When to use Core Data relationships in Swift?

Tags: swift, core-data

I've read through a bunch of tutorials to the best of my ability, but I'm still stumped on how to handle my current application. I just can't quite grasp it.

My application is simply a read-only directory that lists employees by their company, department, or sorted in alphabetical order.

I am pulling down JSON data in the form of:

- Employee

  - Company name
  - Department name
  - First name
  - Last name
  - Job title
  - Phone number
- Company

  - Company name
- Department

  - Company name
  - Department name

As you can see, the information here is pretty redundant. I do not have control over the API and it will remain structured this way. I should also add that not every employee has a department, and not every company has departments.

I need to store this data, so that it persists. I have chosen Core Data to do this (which I'm assuming was the right move), but I do not know how to structure the model in this instance. I should add that I'm very new to databases.

This leads me to some questions:

1. Every example I've seen online uses relationships so that the information can be updated appropriately upon deletion of an object - this will not be the case here since this is read-only. Do I even need relationships for this case then?  These 3 sets of objects are obviously related, so I am just assuming that I should structure it this way. If it is still advised to create relationships, then what do I gain out of creating those relationships in a read-only application? (For instance, does it make searching my data easier and cleaner? etc.)
2. The tutorials I've looked at don't seem to have all of this redundant data. As you can see, "company name" appears as a property in each set of objects. If it would be advised that I create relationships amongst my entities (which are Employee, Company, Department), can someone show me how this *should* look so that I may get an idea of what to do? (This is of course assuming that I should use relationships in my model.)

And I would imagine that this would be the set of rules:

- Each company has many or no departments
- Each department has 1 or many employees
- Each employee has 1 company and 1 (or no) department

Please let me know if I'm on the right track here. If you need clarification, I will try my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use relationships. Make them bi-directional.

The redundant information in your feed doesn't matter, ignore it. If you received partial data it could be used to build the relationships, but you don't need to use it.

You say this data comes from an API, so it isn't read-only as far as the app is concerned. Worry more about how you're going to use the data in the app than how it comes from the server when designing your data model.